# Can't seem to do has-errors inside a div-div tag?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using AngularJS for some basic form validation.

Here's the code so far:

```
<form name="myForm" id="form_id" method="post" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="myField_input" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Field</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : myForm.myField.$invalid && (myForm.myField.$dirty || submitted)}">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="myField" id="myField_input" placeholder="MyField" ng-model="myField" required>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<div class="form-group" ng-controller="AddPropertyController">
    <button class="btn btn-default col-md-4 col-sm-offset-5" ng-click="submitProperty()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

When you click the button, in the controller, $scope.submitted = true;

This has-error field works when I have one div tag with a label and input. But with a div inside a div, it doesn't seem to work anymore and I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: what specifically doesn't work? The class doesn't change or your css isn't being affected? A demo would probably help also

Comment: The css (or html?) isn't being affected. Basically, when I click submit, and myField is empty/invalid, it should highlight it's border as red which it isn't doing.

Comment: Can you at least show an example of what doesn't work?

Comment: That doesn't answer if the class is added or not which can easily be checked in the live html in dev tools. Similarly you can inspect all css rules that apply to any element  Again a demo would help

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwRONr Here is the code... as you can see, show-error makes it possible for me to show an invalid field if the user clicks on the field. However, when the user hits submit, if that field is invalid/empty, it should be red.

Comment: scopes are wacky . Your controller doesn't cover the whole form so `submitted` doesn't exist in the form part, only for the button. Thus the class can't rely on something out of scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is trying to access variable `submitted` when it isn't in scope within your form.

You have wrapped a controller around only the submit button , but not the rest of the form

Changing the controller to wrap the whole form and submit button fixes the issue since `ng-class` can then use the `submitted` variable

Comment: That was pretty much it. I had tags outside so they couldn't connect with one another.